# AngularJS check box filtering not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In [my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/65Pyj/) I can't pass an AngularJS bind value as a parameter to a check box.

In that code I have:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="includeColour('Red')" /> Red<br/>
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="includeColour('Orange')" /> Orange<br/>
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="includeColour('Yellow')" /> Yellow<br/>
```

I just change some it look like below:

```
<div ng-repeat="f in fruit">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-click="includeColour('{{f.colour}}')" />{{f.colour}}  <br />
</div>
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to put `{{}}` while passing the scope variable, Just change

**From**

```
 <input type="checkbox" ng-click="includeColour('{{f.colour}}')" />{{f.colour}}  <br />
```

**To**

```
 <input type="checkbox" ng-click="includeColour(f.colour)" />{{f.colour}}  <br />
```

Working [`JsFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/2cmnL1z0/1/)